# How to plot figures at the end of the for loop MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

Hello I have the following piece of code which plots my results:

```
h1 = figure;
h2 = figure;

for i = 1:5
 figure(h1);
 set(h1, 'Visible', 'off');
 semilogy(0:iter_jac ,resvec_jac,'-*');
 hold on;

 figure(h2);
 set(h2, 'Visible', 'off');
 subplot(3,2,mesh);
plot(trace(:,2),trace_sol(:,1),trace(:,2),trace_sol(:,2),trace(:,2),trace_sol(:,3),trace(:,2),trace_sol(:,4));
 xlabel('arc length');
 ylabel('temperature');
 legend('t = 2.5','t = 5.0','t = 7.5','t = 10');
 title(sprintf('Mesh %d', mesh));
end
```

What this code is doing is basically plotting all the semilogy in one plot while the trace plots in on figure with different subplots. However the problem with this code is that it shows me the figure at every iteration of the for loop (so I see the new results being plotted) even if I set both figures invisible (they still appear for a second). How can I ONLY show the plots once the for loop has ended?

Comment: @AnderBiguri drawnow is actually showing me the figure as it updates

Comment: Hmm, that's weird, because Matlab actually only draws figures at the end of a script unless you set a break point or explicitly call `drawnow` or `pause`. Have you tried to simplify this example, e.g. by only drawing one figure at all?

Comment: I think the problem is in the fact that I call 'figure(h1)', figure(h2) in the for loop, but I dont know how else I would be able to achieve my plots

Comment: Note you aren't calling `figure(h1)` in your loop, instead you're calling `figure(h3)`, which looks like a typo as you've not shown `h3` being created here. You can set the visibility of each figure before the loop too. You might find that calling `hold` triggers the graphics buffer to do something, you can also `hold on` for each figure _once_ before the loop

Comment: Yes sorry I edited my code. Still I dont know how to fix the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `figure(h1)` causes the figure to become visible.

The best way around this is to explicitly use figure and axes handles to do all your work (instead of relying on the current figure/axes and changing those with `figure` or `subplot`). Functions that don't directly take a handle as input can take a name-value pair to set the property `'parent'` to a handle.

```matlab
h1 = figure('Visible', 'off');
h2 = figure('Visible', 'off');
ax1 = axes(h1);
ax1.NextPlot = 'add';  % equivalent to 'hold on'

for i = 1:5
 semilogy(ax1, 0:10, rand(1,11) ,'-*');

 ax2 = subplot(3, 2, i, 'parent', h2);
 plot(ax2, 1, 4, 'o');
 xlabel(ax2, 'arc length');
 ylabel(ax2, 'temperature');
 title(ax2, sprintf('Mesh %d', i));
 legend(ax2, 't = 2.5');

 % Just to demonstrate that figures are not shown until after the loop:
 pause(1);
end

h1.Visible = 'on';
h2.Visible = 'on';
```

[Note I've modified the code also to plot random data, this is just an illustration.]